# Can't find Rows tab on Neo4j brower

Tags: neo4j

I am new to neo4j and I am working on PoC. I succeeded in adding nodes and relations using import queries. But I can't find **Rows** tab to view query result data in tabular format. I can see Tabs **Graph**, **Table**, **Text** and **code**. I want **Rows** option also available in tabs. Please let me know if I have missed anything

Comment: What you are searching is not the `Table` tab ?

Comment: I have a Table tab. But its shows result in json format, not with rows and columns. And in few examples I have seen Rows tag which gives show query result in column and row format which is same what I am expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the way the browser is designed to work. The `Table` tab *is* returning your results in a tabular format. However, if a table column's value is a map (or a node or relationship), then the values in that column will be presented as a map (which looks like a JSON object). Also, if a column's value is a list, it will be presented as an array. Scalar column values (like numbers and strings) will be presented more in the way that you were probably expecting.

So, for example, the `Table` tab for the result of this query:

```
RETURN {a:1, b:2} AS map, [1,2,3] AS list, 123 as number, "abc" as string;
```

would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Exactly the same I am getting ....I was not aware about the fact that it will return JSON boject for nodes. Thanks for describing in detail.